# What is the problem in React hook when retrieve data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following function component

```
import React ,{useState,useEffect} from "react";
export default function Statistics() {
       const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setData(data));
    }, []);


       return (

                data.map(el =>
                    <div>{el.title}</div>
                )

              );
}
```

I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function

**what is the problem in the previous code ?**

Comment: Most probably in the response once you access `data` then the value is not an array. I would try to log to the console to see if it is an object.

Comment: Hey there! Can you log your data so U and us can actually see what is your data's dataType?

Comment: @norbitrial Exactly as you said .... I forgot to write data.hits :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked the API endpoint what you are working with. It seems you need the `hits` property because that's an array. In your current solution `data` is an object which does not have `.map()` to call. If you modify from `data` to `data.hits` then you can iterate through the array with `.map()`.

Try the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
   fetch("https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search")
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => setData(data.hits));
}, []);
```

I hope this helps!